# What version of Crystal Reports does the CrystalReportViewer support?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I am upgrading a project to use the Winforms [CrystalReportViewer control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa665753(v=vs.71).aspx) in Visual Studio 2015.

Looking at the references the assembly version is `13.0.2000.0`.

Can someone tell me which versions of Crystal reports this actually supports?

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) there is no version 13:

```
XI (11)                         BusinessObjects D,P,S
XI R2 (11.5)    Nov 24, 2005    BusinessObjects D,P,S
2008 (12)       Mar 31, 2008    BusinessObjects D
2011 (14.0.x)   Aug 31, 2011    SAP SE   
2013 (14.1.x)                   SAP SE
```

I want to know what version of Crystal I need to install in order to write a report that will work with this control.

Do all of them *work*?

Are they all *supported*?

I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

The current full version of Crystal Reports is 2013 (14.1.x), however the latest runtime for .NET/Visual Studio is 13.x. For Visual Studio 2015 you will need 13.x SP 15 or higher (At the time of this post the latest is SP 18).

From [SAP Wiki](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports+developer+version+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+-+Updates+and+Runtime+Downloads):

- VS 2010 - original release and higher
- VS 2012 - SP 7 and higher
- VS 2013 - SP 9 and higher
- VS 2015 RC - SP14
- VS 2015 - SP 15 and higher

Hopefully the link will stay working as most of the links found for Crystal Reports no longer work.